# How to define the start address of the heap in RAM

Tags: heap-memory, stm32, cortex-m, linker-scripts

I am using a STM32L432KC microcontroller which has two separate internal RAM regions (SRAM1 is 48kB, SRAM2 is 16kB). The memory ranges are not adjacent, so it is not possible to use them as a single block of 64kB.

In the default linker script all data incl. heap and stack are located in SRAM1, whereas SRAM2 is unused. Now I want to locate the heap and stack in SRAM2. However, fail to understand how to tell the linker where the heap is supposed be located.

I found a statement "The HEAP is allocated after the BSS segment" and I found some hints that the heap starts at the "end" symbol. Isn't there an explicit symbol for the linker to locate the heap?

I found a symbol "__malloc_sbrk_start" in the map file, but this appears to be something different (Google didnt help).

Comment: What toolchain?

Comment: Toolchain is "Ac6 STM32 MCU GCC" (SystemWorkbench for STM32). Call me stupid, but I am not able to find any version information.

Comment: So you are using the GNU compiler? The linker is well documented. Have you tried starting with the default linker script and modifying it?

Comment: heap and sbrk come from the C library not the toolchain.  it is behind the malloc implementation in the library.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to modify the linker script. Luckily I found the linker script of your device for AC6 toolchain.

Memory map is

```
MEMORY
{
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 256K
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 48K
SRAM2 (rw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 16K
}
```

To move heap and stack to SRAM2, modify

```
/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x2000c000;    /* end of RAM */
```

to

```
/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x10004000;    /* end of RAM */
```

and

```
  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM
```

to

```
  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >SRAM2
```

Why this works :
PC is loaded in `startup_stm32l432xx.s` with symbol `_estack`. And heap location by symbol `end` in `syscalls.c`.

Answer (score 0):

Just search for symbol `__malloc_sbrk_start` in linker script, there will be something like `__malloc_sbrk_start = .;` (it will be at the end of all defined segments in RAM) and simply replace the `.` with address where start SRAM2 in case of your MCU: `__malloc_sbrk_start = 0x10000000;`